# react-hooks/exhaustive-deps on a function passed via props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm getting the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` warning on an element that calls a function passed via props(`onCountdownEnd`) in the useEffect hook, that is used to direct the application flow on the countdown end:

```
function Countdown(props: { seconds: number; onCountdownEnd: () => void }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(props.seconds);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!count) props.onCountdownEnd();
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count - 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [count]);

  return <span className="text-xxl">00:0{count}</span>;
}
```

`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'.`

What is the correct way to approach this warning? I'm not sure I want to include `props` in the dependancies array here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include the `props` object, since it changes on each render. You should destructure the `props`, and include the exact dependency:

```
function Countdown({ seconds, onCountdownEnd }: { seconds: number; onCountdownEnd: () => void }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(seconds);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!count) onCountdownEnd();
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count - 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [count, onCountdownEnd]);

  return <span className="text-xxl">00:0{count}</span>;
}
```

However, in your code the interval would be cleared and added on each change of count. You can refactor it to use the [`useState` updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to avoid it, and handle `onCountdownEnd` in another `useEffect` block:

```
function Countdown({ seconds, onCountdownEnd }: { seconds: number; onCountdownEnd: () => void }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(seconds);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(current => current - 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []); // no dependencies
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!count) onCountdownEnd();
  }, [count, onCountdownEnd]);

  return <span className="text-xxl">00:0{count}</span>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use a function or a variable in `useEffect`  you have to pass them as dependencies array because the functionality of the callback is based on their value . sometimes you dont need to re-run `useEffect` when they are changed so you can ignore the warning but in your case you can do this:
place this line of code before `useEffect`

```
const onCountdownEnd = {props}
```

and in your `useEffect`

```
if (!count) onCountdownEnd();
```

and finally pass `onCountdownEnd` to the dependency array